# Проверить является ли дерево сбалансированным

Tags: java, бинарное-дерево, дерево

У меня есть свой, ученический вариант реализации двоичного дерева, и у меня задание проверить является ли оно сбалансированным. Если я правильно понял, если нет, пожалуйста поправьте меня, то сбалансированным дерево можно считать если, - любая вершина имеет разницу в длинах правого поддерева и левого, не больше чем на 1. И дело в том что мое дерево которое я должен проверить на сбалансированность, на самом деле не сбалансированное и его узлы выглядят так:

```java
class Leaf<E> implements Comparable<E> {
    private Leaf<E> parent;
    private Leaf<E> right;
    private Leaf<E> left;
    private E element;

    private Leaf(E element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        Leaf<E> node = (Leaf<E>) obj;
        return this.hashCode() - node.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 31;
        hash = hash * 17 + element.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

И как можно увидеть из кода, никакого `balance factor` у меня нет, разумеется, ведь дерево не сбалансированное.

И мой вопрос: как мне проверить является ли дерево сбалансированным или нет? Неужели мне придется проходить по всему дереву? А если оно случайно окажется сбалансированным, на пример в нем всего одно значение, или порядок добавления оказался таким, что в нем баланс получился, но как структура данных оно не сбалансированное?
Как мне точно это выяснить в духе:

```java
boolean isBalanced(Если надо) {
    return хитрый алгоритм проверки;
}
```

Буду очень признателен за любые, конструктивные мысли по этому вопросу.

Comment: 1. Да, нужно обойти всё дерево и сравнивать высоты поддеревьев. 2. Дабы дерево не получилось сразу сбалансированным, при тесте элементы в него стоит добавлять в одном порядке (убывания или возрастания).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это будет полный обход дерева. Рекурсия от двух поддеревьев.

```
public boolean isBalanced() {
     // ...
     return isBalanced(left) && isBalanced(right);
}
```

P.S. И не нужно хранить parent в узле. В 99% случаев можно без него обойтись.